# What does "public ClassName this[ AnEnumType key]" mean in C#?

Tags: c#

I stumble upon a piece of C# code that I don't understand, like this:

```
public class ClassA {
public ClassB this[EnumA key] {
    get {
            ClassB b;
            dictionaryB.TryGetValue(key, out b);
            return b;
    }

}
```

...
}

I don't understand the syntax of "ClassB this[EnumA key] {...", what is it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This is the indexing operator.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/indexers/using-indexers) It's used by collections most usually to give a callee a direct reference to an object in its storage.